# Angular material grid, rowHeight fit

Tags: angular, grid, angular-material

I am currently working with different content, with different materials Grid, I would like my tiles to be automatically height, but using the  tag, but I I'm not the result I want to get, so I have to use the  tag.

my code:

```
  <mat-grid-list class="quot-service-grid" cols="9" [rowHeight]="fit">
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="6" class="quot-service-element">

      <div class="quot-service-inf">
        <h2 class="quot-service-name lw-grey">{{service.name}}</h2>
        <p class="lw-grey">{{service.description}}</p>
      </div>

    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile class="left quot-service-comment" [colspan]="3">
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
```

Thanks

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10395) may help. It seems that `fit` will only work if the height of the grid-list or its container is set. Also, unless you have a variable called fit on your ts file, you should remove the property binding  from rowHeight on your template.

Answer (score 12):

As you can see here: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10395

> Regrettably, Angular has the worst Google material implementation (in comparison to VueJS/Vuetify or React/MaterialUI),..

In your case Angular Flex Layout would be the better solution: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

Some demos are here online; https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

Comment: this is still the case in the mid of 2021

Answer (score 0):

it should be rowHeight="fit" without bracket.

Answer (score 0):

I know my response came too late but you can try the following work around,

First, give an id to you  tag and set your rowHeight to the height of the tag plus your preferred padding. Your complete code will look like below;

```html
 <mat-grid-list class="quot-service-grid" cols="9" [rowHeight]="{{ Number(check.offsetHeight + 50 ) }}">
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="6" class="quot-service-element">

      <div #check class="quot-service-inf">
        <h2 class="quot-service-name lw-grey">Service Name</h2>
        <p class="lw-grey">Service Description</p>
      </div>

    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile class="left quot-service-comment" [colspan]="3">
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
```